# Very slow write speeds on ubuntu server

Tags: ubuntu

Specs:
Supermicro 2U Server 
H8DG6-F Motherboard
2x AMD 6272 2.1ghz 16 Core
32GB of ram
1 250GB hd
4 WD Red 3TB hds

Background:
I bought this server on ebay and added the hard drives.
I installed Ubuntu server 16.04 32bit os on the 250GB drive.
I created an mdadm raid 5 array with the 4 WD Red drives
I used this guide for creating it: 
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-create-raid-arrays-with-mdadm-on-ubuntu-16-04
I also installed gcp so I could see what my write speeds were.

Issue:
From a ntfs external drive hooked up via USB copying files between 1 to 2 gb I was receiving <1MBs write speeds to both the raid array

Troubleshooting steps:
I have rebuilt the array 4 times now 
I have mounted the external drive using code "mount -o big_writes /dev/sda1 /media"

This is my first server and I do not know if it is hooked up correctly inside. I just know I can see the drives in the os and at boot. I am very new to ubuntu

Answer (score 0):

There are a large number of possibilities, I doubt I've covered them all, but things to look at -

1. (Not an answer, but very relevant) - you probably don't want to be using
   RAID5 on this - Software RAID 5 is slow, and RAID 5 does not provide
   great reliability (See this [link](http://www.zdnet.com/article/raidfail-dont-use-raid-5-on-small-arrays/)) and your system is to small for
   RAID10.   If its an option, seriously considering replacing the disks
   or otherwise modifying things so you can use RAID1.   (Maybe replace the
   250 gig drive with a 3tb drive, set aside a couple of partitions and 
   have 2 RAID1 sets of close to 3TB and then use LVM to make them into
   a close to 6TB data set).  This will be way faster, more reliable and
   simpler.
2. Has the RAID array finished building?   If not, that may be consuming most of the IO - the output of cat /proc/mdadm would be useful (and would show if this build is happening)
3. It would be a good idea to remove the USB copying from the equation as it creates more possibility that the problem is not with the RAID array.  Try using disk performance testing tools - these can be as simple as using "dd","pv", but is better with something like "Bonnie++"
4. The output of fdisk might be useful, as it could show byte alignment issues.  Its also, however, possible that there is a firmware limitation which gives really bad performance on disks greater then t2b  (I've run into this with some older HP gear).  This shouldn't be a problem with newer drives though.